# How to create css based breadcrumb which supports IE8

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Can some one provide me some good css example to create breadcrumbs for my asp.net application. Which should support IE 8.

I was trying this link http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-breadcrumbs but it is working in Crome not in IE8. Please someone help me.

Thanks
Gulrej

Comment: What exactly is it that isn't working in IE8? Does it partially work? What features are not working? Have you tried doing anything to fix it?

Comment: The arrow is not showing. When it is showing in crome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're trying to use contains several features that are not supported by IE8.

- `border-radius`
  If you need rounded corners, this can be made to work using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/)
- `box-shadow`
  Also use CSS3Pie for this.
- `text-shadow`
  There is no good way to get this working in IE8. Sorry.
- `linear-gradient`
  Also use CSS3Pie for this.
- `rgba()` colours
  And again, CSS3Pie for this too, although there are some quirks to watch out for.
- `::before` and `::after`
  Actually, `:before` and `:after` are supported in IE8, but need a single colon, not a double colon.

As you can see from my comments above, most of these features can be made to work with a bit of effort and a few hacks, but by default they are not supported by the browser.

In addition, some other browsers may need vendor prefixes for some of these features. In particular, the gradient styles should be provided with prefixes if you want to support all common browsers.

Your options:

1. Write your CSS in a way that allow sensible fall-backs -- eg a sensible plain colour background for IE8 that is overridden by the gradient for browsers that support it.
2. Use a library like CSS3Pie, which attempts to make IE8 more compatible with modern standards. But be aware that if you use it a lot, it has been known to slow IE8 down quite badly.

Comment: I have changed the CSS....and its working now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Spudley, One more help. Now I want to implement this breadcrumb in my application. I want initially my breadcrumb will be all gray, now when user will complete 1st task, then 1st li will be green, when user complete 2nd task then 1st and 2nd will be green....like this go on. How I should implement this. Is there a way, we can use some javascript or I need to write some c# code. Can you please suggest me what will be the best way to implement it.

Comment: @Gulrej - Use a CSS class that overrides the default colour. Then it's just a case of setting the current item to have that class. How you do that it up to you; it could be Javascript or it could be in your back-end code; depends how your site works.

Comment: (by the way -- in cases like this, it might be better to ask a fresh question on SO rather than asking for more help in the comments... a new question would be seen by everyone on SO, but the comment is only likely to be seen by one person, so you have more chance of getting help with a new question)